# How to display in Django Templates Embedded Models?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, django-templates, djongo

models.py

```
class Decomposicao(models.Model):    
    tirosina = models.BooleanField('tirosina')
    fenilalanina = models.BooleanField('fenilalanina')
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class SDF(models.Model):
    numero = models.IntegerField('SDF', unique=True, primary_key=True)

    decomposicao = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=Decomposicao,
    )

    data_insercao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.numero)
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    data = {}
    if request.method == 'GET':
        search = request.GET
        search = search['sdf']
        if search.startswith("SDF") or search.startswith("sdf"):
            sdf = SDF.objects.get(pk=search[3:])            
        else: 
            sdf = SDF.objects.get(pk=search)
    data['sdf'] = sdf
    data['numero'] = format(sdf.numero, '04d')
    return render(request, 'app/busca.html', data)
```

I'm using mongodb and django, so I decided to utilize djongo as the connector - [djongo doc](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/get-started/) - that been said I'm trying to display the content I find on querys in django templates - busca.html - but I can't find a way to display the Embedded models.

busca.html

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}

{% block cabecalho %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<title>SDF{{ numero }}</title>
{% endblock%}

{% block conteudo %}

<section class="bg-light">
<div class="container ">
    <div class="col-lg-12 h-100 text-center text-lg-left my-auto">
        <h1 class="text-muted medium mb-4 mb-lg-0">SDF{{ numero }</h1>
        <br>
        {{ sdf }}
    </div>
</div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Doing that only display the number - 'numero' - of the sdf.

Thanks.

Comment: but how do I display all the data of an SDF? without going one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{ sdf }}` calls the `__str__` method of your model,  which returns numero as defined. To display all the fields use `{{ sdf.numero }}`, `{{ sdf.decomposicao }}`, `{{ sdf.data_insercao }}`. I believe that you could access fields of your embedded model with dot notation, for example `{{ sdf.decomposicao.tirosina }}`.